# Unable to call a Model within a Service in sails.js

Tags: sails.js

Are you able to make calls to Models from within a Service in Sails because I can't seem to get it to work at the moment.

Controller:

```
index: function (req, res) {
var results = StudentService.findAllStudents();
return res.view('student/index', {
  students: results
}); },
```

Service:

```
findAllStudents: function (options, done) {
    Student.find({}).exec(function (err, results) {
      if (err != null && err.message != null) {
        sails.log.error(err.message);
      } else {
        return results;
      }
    });
  }
```

During a debug, I'm noticing that the find method doesn't seem to be even called. Does sails.js's service layer have no access to connections? The model code works fine when I move it back to the controller layer. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your service code to accept a callback.

```
findAllStudents: function (options, callback) {
    Student.find({}).exec(function (err, results) {
      return callback(err, results);
    });
  }
```

Change the controller code to pass a callback function to work with the result or handle error.

```
index: function (req, res) {
    var opts = {};
    var results = StudentService.findAllStudents(opts, function(err, results){
        return res.view('student/index', {
            students: results
        }); 
    });
},
```